# How can I make one method to rotate multiple number of characters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if (waitinganimation == true)
            {
                RotateCharacters(animators[2]);
            }

            if (!endRot)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                        goalRotation,
                        animators[0].transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
                animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                endRot = Mathf.Approximately(angleThisFrame, angleToGoal);
            }
            {
                animators[0].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
                animators[1].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RotateCharacters(int[] CharactersIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CharactersIndex.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!endRotation)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -90f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                        goalRotation,
                        animators[CharactersIndex[i]].transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, 100 * Time.deltaTime);

                animators[CharactersIndex[i]].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                endRotation = Mathf.Approximately(angleThisFrame, angleToGoal);
            }
            else
            {
                animators[CharactersIndex[i]].SetBool("Magic Pack", true);
            }
        }
    }

    bool waitinganimation = false;
    IEnumerator WaitForAnimation()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        waitinganimation = true;
    }
```

First I'm rotating `animators[0]` and `[1]` for specific angle goal and then I'm rotating `animators[2]` for another angle goal. Instead I want to use the RotateCharacters method for multiple rotations.

If I'm calling the method once: `RotateCharacters(2);` and then for example: `RotateCharacters(0,1);` or better: `RotateCharacters(animators[2]);` or `RotateCharacters(animators[0], animators[1]);`

So in the Update I will have two lines:

```
RotateCharacters(animators[2], Quaternion angle);
RotateCharacters(animators[0], animators[1], Quaternion angle);
```

So it will rotate all the 3 at the same time but the first one `animators[2]` will rotate to a specific angle and then the two others `animators[0]` and `animators[1]` will rotate to another angle.

Not how it should looks like but the idea is to make multiple rotations.
But I messed up the whole method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword.  A params collection **must** be the last defined parameter as it collects *all* subsequent extra parameters into the array.  Basically it's a short-hand for creating an array from 'optional' parameters.

Example:

```
void RotateAll(Quaternion rotation, params Animator[] anims) {
    foreach ( var anim in anims )
        ApplyRotation(rotation, anim); // However you want to actually apply the rotation
}
```

and call it like:

```
RotateAll(new Quaternion(), animators[0], animators[2]); //etc
```